# Regex not matching URL Params

Tags: html, regex, web-services, opayo

I am currently working on a stub server I can plug into a webpage so I do not need to hit sagepay every time I test my payment screen. I need the server to receive a request from the web page and use the dynamic parameters contained in the URL to build the server response. The stub uses regex targets to pick out the parameters I need and add them to the response.

I am using [this stub server](https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j)

I built the accepted URL piece by piece, using the regex tester contained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to test each bit of logic. The expressions work separately, but when I try to join two or more of them together they refuse to work. Each parameter is separated by an ampersand (&) and the name of the parameter.

Here is a sample of the parameters:

> paymentType=A&amount=147.06&policyUid=07ef493b-0000-0000-6a05-9fa4d6a5b5ad&paymentMethod=A&script=Retail/accept.py&scriptParams=uid=07ef461a-0000-0000-6a059fa44a8870bf&invokePCL=true&paymentType=A&description=New Business Payment&firstName=Adam&surname=Har&addressLine1=20 Potters Road&city=London&postalCode=EC1 4JS&payerUid=07ef3ff7-0000-0000-6a05-9fa42e92d56b&cardType=valid&continuousAuthority=true&makeCurrent=true

and in a list for ease of reading (without &'s)

```
paymentType=A 
amount=147.06
policyUid=07ef493b-0000-0000-6a05-9fa4d6a5b5ad 
paymentMethod=A
script=Retail/accept.py
scriptParams=uid=07ef461a-0000-0000-6a059fa44a8870bf&invokePCL=true&paymentType=A 
description=New Business Payment 
firstName=Adam 
surname=Har
addressLine1=20 Chase road 
city=London 
postalCode=EC1 3PF
payerUid=07ef3ff7-0000-0000-6a05-9fa42e92d56b 
cardType=valid
continuousAuthority=true 
makeCurrent=true
```

And here is my accepted URL parameters with the regex logic:

> paymentType=A&amount=([0-9]+.[0-9]{2})&policyUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)&paymentMethod=([a-zA-Z]+)&script=([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+.py)&scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}=(([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)))&description=([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+s)&firstName=[A-Za-z]&surname=[A-Za-z]&addressLine1=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&city=([a-zA-Z ]+)&postalCode=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&payerUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)&cardType=[a-zA-Z]+&continuousAuthority=[a-zA-Z]+&makeCurrent=[a-zA-Z]+

again in a list:

```
registerPayment?outputType=xml
country=GB
paymentType=A
amount=([0-9]+.[0-9]{2})
policyUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)
paymentMethod=([a-zA-Z]+)
script=([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+.py)
scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}=(([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)))
description=([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+s)
firstName=[A-Za-z]
surname=[A-Za-z]
addressLine1=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
city=([a-zA-Z ]+)
postalCode=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
payerUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)
cardType=[a-zA-Z]+
continuousAuthority=[a-zA-Z]+
makeCurrent=[a-zA-Z]+
```

My question is; why does my regex and sample match ok seperately, but dont when I put them all together ?

Additional question:

I am using the logic (([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+))) for the whole ScriptParams parameter (the &'s here are part of the parameter.) If I just want to get the 'uid' part and leave the rest, what expression would I need to target this (it is made up of A-z a-z 0-9 and dashes)?

thank you

**UPDATE**

I have tweaked your answer slightly, because the stub server I am using will not accept the `(?:[\s-])` when it loads the file containing the URL templates. I have also incorporated a lot of % and 0-9 because the request is UTF encoded before it is matched (which I had not anticipated), and a few of the params have rogue spaces beyond my control. Other than that, your solution worked great :)

Here is my new version of the scriptParams regex: 
`&scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}%3d[-A-Za-z0-9]+`

This accepts the whole parameter, and works fine in the regex tester. Now when I link anything after this part, there is an unsuccessful match.

I do not understand why this is a problem as the regex seem to string together nicely otherwise. Any ideas are appreciated.

Here is the full regex:

```
paymentType=[-%a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&amount=[0-9]+.[0-9]{2}&policyUid=([-A-Za-z0-9]+)&paymentMethod=([%a-zA-Z0-9]+)&script=[%/.a-zA-Z0-9]+&scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}%3d[-A-Za-z0-9]+&description=[%a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&firstName=[-%A-Za-z0-9]+&surname=[-%A-Za-z0-9]+&addressLine1=[-%a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&city=[-%a-zA-Z 0-9]+&postalCode=[-%a-zA-Z 0-9]+&payerUid=([-A-Za-z0-9]+)&cardType=[%A-Za-z0-9]+&continuousAuthority=[A-Za-z]+&makeCurrent=[A-Za-z]+
```

And here is the full set of URL params (with UTF encoding present):

```
paymentType=A&amount=104.85&policyUid=16a9cc22-0000-0000-5a96-5654d9a31f92&paymentMethod=A%20&script=RetailQuotes%2FacceptQuote.py%20&scriptParams=uid%3d16a9c958-0000-0000-5a96-565435311d07%26invokePCL%3dtrue%26paymentType%3dA%20&description=New%2520Business%2520Payment&firstName=Adam&surname=Har%20&addressLine1=26%2520Close&city=Potters%2520Town&postalCode=EC1%25206LR%20&payerUid=16a9c24e-0000-0000-5a96-5654b3f956e0&cardType=valid%20&continuousAuthority=true&makeCurrent=true
```

Thank you

PS
(Solved the server problem. Was a slight mistake I was making in the usage of URL params.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your regex not all work, some are missing quantifiers, others have a `$` for some reason and some parameters are even missing! Here's what they should have been:

```
paymentType=A
amount=([0-9]+.[0-9]{2})
policyUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
paymentMethod=([a-zA-Z]+)
script=([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+.py)
scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}=(([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)+))
invokePCL=([a-z]+)
paymentType=A
description=([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)
firstName=[A-Za-z]+
surname=[A-Za-z]+
addressLine1=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
city=([a-zA-Z ]+)
postalCode=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
payerUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
cardType=[a-zA-Z]+
continuousAuthority=[a-zA-Z]+
makeCurrent=[a-zA-Z]+
```

And combined, you get:

```
paymentType=A&amount=([0-9]+.[0-9]{2})&policyUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)&paymentMethod=([a-zA-Z]+)&script=([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+.py)&scriptParams=[a-zA-Z]{3}=(([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)+))&invokePCL=([a-z]+)&paymentType=A&description=([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)&firstName=[A-Za-z]+&surname=[A-Za-z]+&addressLine1=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&city=([a-zA-Z ]+)&postalCode=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+&payerUid=([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)&cardType=[a-zA-Z]+&continuousAuthority=[a-zA-Z]+&makeCurrent=[a-zA-Z]+
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/tV6fF1)

[Note, I took your regexes where they matched and ran minimal edits to them].

For your second question, I'm not sure what you mean by the Uid part and that `&` are part of the parameter. Given that there are 3 Uids in the url with similar format (policy, scriptparams, user), you will have to put them in the expression, unless you know a specific pattern to the scriptparams' Uid.

In the expression below, I made use of the fact that only scriptparams' `uid` was in lowercase:

```
uid=[0-9a-f]+(?:-[0-9a-f]+)+
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/xG4lG1)

Comment: thank you. Had taken a few samples from varying sources and thought the *$ was the repeat until finished command. Your reviewed regex works great. Now I am somehow loosing the scriptParams uid in the server! It is in the request but not in the String the server tries to match with the sample URL..... programming eh! Thanks for your help

Comment: @a.hrdie Haha, okay, I hope you get it sorted out :) You're welcome! ^^

Comment: Hi, updated my question due to ongoing problems. Your answer worked for my test data but I had to tweak a small amount for the actual form data. Please see updated question for more detials

Comment: @a.hrdie There's a problem I think with the URL. There are missing `&` and `=` signs... (like there's no `&` before `Invoke` or `=` shortly after) Are you sure it's a correct one? Might as well start the regex from scratch...

Comment: @a.hrdie Okay. I take it as all's working well. Let me know if there's anything you need me for and I'll try to do the necessary :)